# Right places for relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

> The chart shows the percentage of usage of most common means,WHICH ARE
>   DESKTOP COMPUTER, LAPTOP AND MOBILE PHONE, of access to buy tickets
>   USED by people from Australia, the UK and Malaysia.

I have many trouble when it comes to use relative clause in order to give complete information.Here I would like to say what the means are and people who used these means are from Australia, the UK and Malaysia.But I am not sure if I can write "the means" just before the word of and when I used the word "used" after tickets, it sounds like I am talking about the tickets but not "the means"..in other way, I want "the means" to be my relative pronoun when I add the word "used" after tickets..

How can we place relative clauses ?

Comment: @Ian  MacDonald  nah I asked that question also          ♥

Comment: _The chart shows the percentage of usage of the most common means of access—which are desktop computers, laptops and mobile phones—used by people from Australia, the UK and Malaysia to buy tickets._

That's how I would say it.

Comment: You could also just put the list in parentheses, rather than using a relative clause.

Comment: @Murat: I think you need a lot more help than just a rundown on using relative clauses. Really, this question is Off Topic *proofreading* (or at least, it *needs* proofreading). Amir has helpfully provided you with a decent "rewrite", but you'd probably be more at home on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) if you have any further questions.